# Replacement for deprecated function mysql_connect

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

So I have this Amazon Web Service database all set up

I'm working off an old tutorial for an application that I'm planning on using it with.

I noticed that mysql_connect was deprecate when I looked it up.

What can I use as an alternative? How can I connect to my amazon database?

```
<?
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die ("Can't connect to database server");
mysql_select_db("videoRecorderDemo") or die ("Can't select database");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
?>
```

I get this error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'username'@'192.168.1.1' (using password: YES) in /www/zxq.net/r/e/d/red5vptest/htdocs/utility/db.php on line 2
Can't connect to database server
```

No matter what credentials I use.
It also doesn't help that Amazon's code samples show you connecting in an entirely different way.

Comment: There's a couple of options for you - either of the options mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons). Yes, if AWS docs use `mysql` library examples, well they shouldn't! `:)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The documentation for PHP says](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

/*
 * This is the "official" OO way to do it,
 * BUT $connect_error was broken until PHP 5.2.9 and 5.3.0.
 */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The error message you are getting is unrelated to the deprecation of `mysql_connect`. The MySQL username and password you're using ("username" and "password" in your code) are wrong — if you don't know the correct values, check the documentation for the version of MySQL you installed. (You may need to create a user and/or database.)

As several others have mentioned, the supported alternatives to the mysql extension are [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) and [PDO MySQL](http://php.net/pdo_mysql).

Answer (score 2):

MysqlI (mysql improved) is the successor for mysql.

```
$Link = new mysqli($Hostname, $Username, $Password, $Database);
$Result = $Link->query('SELECT ...');
$Rows = $Result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy alternative to the MySQL extension is MySQLi. Instead of

```
mysql_connect("host", "username", "password")
```

... you could connect using e.g.

```
$db = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password");
```

It's probably worth reading this helpful tutorial:
http://phpmaster.com/avoid-the-original-mysql-extension-1/

Answer (score 0):

The manual suggests mysqli as an alternative
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php